# Why is chirpy not creating a debug mashed javascript file?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, chirpy

I have hte following mash.chirp.config file

```
<root>
  <FileGroup Name="podPlayers.debug.js"> 
    <File Path="core.js" Minify="false" />
    <File Path="contentArea.js" Minify="false" />
    <File Path="searchbar.js" Minify="false" />
  </FileGroup>

  <FileGroup Name="podPlayers.min.js">
    <File Path="core.js" Minify="true" />
    <File Path="contentArea.js" Minify="true" />
    <File Path="searchbar.js" Minify="true" />
  </FileGroup>
</root>
```

When I save this Chirpy generates 2 files, `podPlayers.js` and `podPlayers.min.js`.  However it does NOT create `podPlayers.debug.js".

Any idea why?  This is with Chirpy 2.0.0.4

Answer (score 1):

I admittedly had a similar problem; I removed the references to a few files inside the FileGroup element, but noticed that my mashed file still contained them even after the changes were saved; It was as if Chirpy didn't realise it had been changed.

I was using the Google Closure Compiler as my default minifier for JS. While by no means a guaranteed work-around, what resolved this for me was to turn off Offline Compression (which I had enabled), re-save the file, then turned it back on again.

The option to do this can be found in Visual Studio 2010 here: Tools -> Options -> Chirpy -> Google Closure Compiler.

To clarify, I'm using Chirpy v2.0.0.4 as well.